# Attaching css stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I have a very strange problem that never happen to me. I normally attach css as always and in Visual Studio code or in local file is working perfect. `<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">`
But when I host page all css is gone(I try 4 of them). Then I must reload all linked stylesheet to be working again(special extension in chrome). Someone have any idea why this happen?

Comment: Have you checked the dev console to make sure the URL is correct?

Comment: Does your browser's style editor pull that style sheet in as a resource?  Any console errors?

Comment: No console log, but in sources there is 404 page css but html is my and then I reload links and my css appears. I try 4 hosting page including the pay one and in every one the css is different but not mine

Answer (score 2):

Edit: As the user suggest, also first try to clear the browser cache, deleting cookies and data, before continuing troubleshooting.

The most common problem causing that issue is the location of the .css file, it depends on how you are hosting the site but perhaps setting an absolute path to the file can help you discard the location issue. Also you are telling something about a chrome extension, did you try loading the page in another browser for troubleshooting?

Comment: I forgot to check it and it works on other browsers, but now why this is not working on chrome?

Comment: Try disabling all the extension that you have active in the current chrome session. If that works, you can enable one at a time looking for the specific conflict. If you find a specific extension that is causing the trouble you can search for the specific solution.

Comment: Problem was with cache in chrome. I had to delete all cookies and data from browser and now its working

Answer (score 0):

Useful information: To avoid the problem of caching styles and scripts, it is recommended to use version

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mydomain.com/css/style?v=1598035492054">
```

I recommend that you read [this article](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/#query-strings)